# Converge or Diverge

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

If $(x_n)$ is a sequence of real numbers such that $x_n > 0$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and $(x_n \cdot \sqrt{n}) \rightarrow 1$. Does $\sum x_n$ converge or diverge?

I am a little lost with this one. We know $(\sqrt{n})$ diverges to $\infty$ but other than that, I don't know where to go from here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that 
$$x_n\sqrt{n}=\frac{x_n}{\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}}$$
and since $\sum_n\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$ diverges, you can apply the [limit comparison test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_comparison_test) to conclude that $\sum_nx_n$ diverges.

Comment: I see how using the limit comparison test works, but I'm just questioning why we have the assumption $(x_n \sqrt{2}) \rightarrow 1$.

Comment: $x_n\sqrt{n}\to 1$ is equivalent to $\frac{x_n}{\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}}\to 1$, and this is what allows you to use the limit comparison test.

Comment: Is it possible to prove this using the direct comparison test?

Comment: Probably, but the information you were given makes using the limit comparison test the natural thing to do.